# Fourier Series: Is $\cos(n \pi)$ the same thing as $\cos(-n\pi)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For a Fourier series calculation, if you have bounds from $-1$ to $+1$ and you are plugging it into the function $\cos(n \pi)$, would it result in $0$? Thank you for any clarification.

Comment: Cosine is an even function.

Comment: As Bongers said, $\cos$ is an even function. Even more, we know that $$\forall n\in\mathbb Z,\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n.$$

Answer (score 1):

Cosine is an even function, i.e. $\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$.

Thus, as a result,

$$\cos(-n \pi) = \cos(n \pi)$$

The integrals of even functions $f$, further, can be given by

$$\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx = 2 \cdot \int_0^a f(x)dx$$

If $f$ was odd (and thus $f(-x)=-f(x)$), as with the $\sin(x)$ function, however, we'd have

$$\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx = 0$$

Since $\cos(x)$ is an even function, though, the first integral applies. (Not the second as you posit in your question.)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have another followup question: when you are solving for a_(sub)n and b_(sub)n, is there a simple way to tell if one of them is equal to zero based on whether the function is even or odd? Or do you have to perform all the calculations? Thank you again

Comment: I always perform all of the calculations just for its own sake. I guess if you're on a symmetric interval $(-a,a)$ and the function is odd, the cosine terms (the $a_n$) might disappear, and if the function is even then the sine terms (the $b_n$) would, but this is just a guess.

Comment: There might be more conditions to it, though, so it's just a guess.

Comment: Okay thank you. I will just calculate it all out to be safe.